# Why do we need to calculate this as a conditional probability?

Tags: conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

I am trying to solve this problem:

> A motorist just had an accident. The accident is minor with probability $0.75$ and is otherwise major. Let $b$ be a positive constant. If the accident is minor, then the loss amount follows a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,b]$. If the accident is major, then the loss amount follows a uniform distribution on the interval $[b,3b]$. The median loss amount due to this accident is $672$. Calculate $b$.

From my point of view, we knew that
$$ P(X \leq b) = 0.75 $$
Hence, the median is lies in $[0, b]$. The cumulative function for values in this range is $$\frac{x}{b}$$ Then, to find $b$, we just need to solve
$$ \frac{x}{b} = 0.5.$$

However, as the answer given, to find the value of $b$, we need to solve
$$ P(X \leq x \mid x < b) = 0.5, $$
which is
$$ \frac{1}{0.75b} = 0.5. $$

May I know why do we need this conditional probability? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure where you are getting that cumulative function from.  Is that the conditional cumulative function, given that x < b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is the amount of the loss, then $F(x)$ should only reach 0.75 at b, not 1.
The median is the value of x where $F(x) = 0.5$.
You are correct that it climbs linearly from 0 at X=0. The area is $\frac{bh}{2} = 0.5$. The slope is $\frac{0.75}{b}$, so at x, the height is $\frac{0.75x}{b}$, giving
$$\frac{1}{2}x\cdot\frac{0.75x}{b} = 0.5
$$
The median x is given as 672.  Solve for b.